# htaccess | apply query only to a part of the url

Tags: .htaccess

I've a rule in my .htaccess, but I want to apply it only to a specific URL, as below:

```
A. mysite.net/index.php?option=com_contact  ** this should be blocked
B. mysite.net/admin/index.php?option=com_contact  ** this should work
```

The rule below works fine for A, but it also blocks B. 
How to block only A?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=(com_contact)$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: because the query string for both is same so make a difference by URI

Comment: change second line to RewriteRule !^admin - [F]

Comment: Thanks Mohammed  !^admin seems to work !

Comment: Glad to help , Thanks